# Batch script the same on both PC's but not working?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hello I have 2 batch files, it works perfectly on one machine but not so perfect on another.

Here is the code.

```sh
set /p "ln=" <"C:\LoginSystem\userl.txt"
set "%ln:&="&set "%"
set realuser=%user:"=%
echo %realuser%
```

So on my machine it shows like this:

```
    echo Liam
    Liam
```

On the other machine it shows like this:

```
    echo "=
    "=
```

It's the exact same machines only difference is one is running Windows 8 (working) and the other windows 7 ("=)

EDIT:

Thank you all for the answers, I managed to solve this by editing the way the userl.txt file is generated to make it display just the name, e.g "Liam" without quotes. Then use this

set /p user=

That seems to work for what I need s there is only 1 value ever going to be in that file.

Thank you all!

Comment: I think SO's syntax highlighter will help you to spot the problem...

Comment: Is it the set realuser=%user:"=% because of the " in there? I did that to remove any " from the names as it has to be removed, not sure why it works on the windows 8 and not the windows 7 though

Comment: Test it again in a new cmd window on Windows 8 and verify that it works.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `echo %thisvariabledoesnoexist:"=%` will show the same result.

The reason for the observed output is that the variable `%user%`, that seems that have to been assigned a value in the `set "%ln:&="&set "%"` line, did not get any value.

The problem is probably that the input line does not contain the required value or the format of the input line is different from the expected one.

Comment: Hi MC ND, thank you for your answer but it didn't solve my problem, the file userl.txt is the same on both computers and so is the script. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @LeeWork, Can you include the contents of the `userl.txt` file?

Comment: if I put `Liam` on line one in that file then I get the same error on Windows 8.1 that the OP gets on Windows 7 - plus an error message.

Comment: @foxidrive, from the OP code, it seems the input is something like `var=value&var=value&var=value` with or without quotes (see the &=&set). Some of the values in the line interfer in the process. As the content of the file is the same in the two systems (from previous comment), maybe, there is some exclamation on data and different delayed expansion configuration in each system. Or different pagecodes. Or .... It is easier with the input file.

Comment: Yes, knowing what is inside the file will make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

As MC ND has pointed out, the critical point is that variable `user` must be defined to work properly. If it is not defined, then you get your problem result.

I don't see how identical user1.txt files being processed on two machines with identical batch scripts can possibly give different results as you describe.

Strike that, I can think of one way, but it is a long shot. The assumption is the first two lines are supposed to define the `user` variable, perhaps along with other variables. But suppose the first two lines do not define the `user` variable on either machine. Perhaps `user` is already defined on the machine that "works" before the script is even run, and it is not defined on the other machine. That is the only thing I can come up with that would yield the result you describe.

I do see one thing that concerns me in your code. The following line of code implies that sometimes you get quotes in your input.

```
set realuser=%user:"=%
```

You state that quotes in your value interfere, so you remove them. But you are removing them too late! The prior line may not set all the values properly if there are quotes in the value of `ln`.

Try the following:

```
set /p "ln=" <"C:\LoginSystem\userl.txt"
set "ln=%ln:"=%"
set "%ln:&="&set "%"
echo %user%
```